# Cannot connect postgresql db to my netcore web project (DigitalOcean Cloud)

Tags: postgresql, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean

I want to use my postgresql db from digital ocean in my webpage. Before i create this db, i have a free one for test and is working fine, but this new its not working.
I can connect from pgadmin to the db without problem.

My web project is a net core 2.1.

My connection strings

- (1) From my test db (working):

`optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql( "Server=my-server;Port=5432;Database=mydb; User Id=myuser;Password=mypsw;");`

- (2) From digital ocean db (not working):

`optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Server=myserver;Port=25060;Database=defaultdb; User Id=doadmin;Password=mypsw;SslMode=Require");`

If i use the (1) connection it works perfect, but when i change to (2) connection throw me the error message.
This is the error message:

**“The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.”**

My web its certificated with Let’s Encrypt, certbot.

Tell me if you need more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, my problem was the ssl certificate, letsencrypt its a self-signed certificate and with sslmode=require, the connection fail.
So you have to add this parameter `Trust Server Certificate=true`.

`optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Server=myserver;Port=25060;Database=defaultdb; User Id=doadmin;Password=mypsw;SslMode=Require;Trust Server Certificate=true");`

Source: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/security.html#encryption-ssltls

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!! This was 5 years ago but it just saved me :p

Comment: what if we cannot use Trust Server Certificate? How do we create proper certificate?